# Seleccionar varios divs en base al id de un ejemento hijo

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo un div con la clase "property" y dentro tengo mas elementos pero entre ellos un div con una imagen y un span, este span tiene un id="star", lo que necesito es llegar a todos los divs "property" que tenga ese id

Lo que tengo en mente por ahora:
document.querySelectorAll('.property > #star')

Ejemplo abstracto:

```
<div class="property">
    <div class="main-img">
        <img>
        <span id="start">contenido</span>
    </div>

    div.contenido
</div>
```

A final deberia de tener un array con todos los div.property [div.property, div.property...]

Comment: el problema es que los id son únicos, no podrías tener varios span con el id start

Comment: en lugar de usar `id` usa el atributo `name` o `class`,  `document.getElementsByClassName()` o `document.getElementsByName()`

Comment: En HTML no se deben repetir **id**, por lo tanto planteate lo mismo pero con clases. Lo del querySelectorAll ya es correcto tal como lo planteas, pero suponiendo que cambias el `id="star"` por `class="start"` tan solo debes cambiarlo por `document.querySelectorAll('.property .star')`

Comment: los id son únicos, no pueden repetirse, sería mejor trabajar con clases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería servirte, pero debes realizar cambios tal como ya te han comentado en la pregunta.

El cambio es quitar todos los `id="start"` y cambiarlos por `class="start"`, pues los **id=** en **HTML nunca deben repetirse**.

Una vez hecho eso, y sabiendo tu estructura actual, puedes localizarlos así:

```js
var arr = []
document.querySelectorAll('.property span[class=start]').forEach(function(el) {
  let divProperty = el.closest(".property")
  arr.push(divProperty)
})

console.log(arr.length)
```

```html
<div class="property">
  <div class="main-img">
    <img>
    <span class="start">contenido</span>
  </div>
  div.contenido
</div>
<div class="property">
  <div class="main-img">
    <img>
    <span class="start">contenido</span>
  </div>
  div.contenido
</div>
<div class="property">
  <div class="main-img">
    <img>
    <span class="NOstart">contenido</span>
  </div>
  div.contenido
</div>
```